# asp session issue in Load balanced Sql Always on Failover cluster

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, load-balancing, failovercluster

I have a very particular scenario here. A .Net website which has Load balanced Webserver (2 Nodes), routes traffic to Internal Load balancer which then sends traffic to Sql servers in Always on Failover cluster(2 nodes and no Quorum).

Asp session is stored in Sql server. 
Issues 
1. The webpage loads once and when opened in another tab keeps waiting for response. (Only in Google-CHROME). To load the webpage it needs the cookie to be deleted (Developer tools > Application > cookie)

2. This does not happen when tested in Standalone mode (1 Webserver, 1 Sql server and no Load balancer)

3.I have tried InProc and State server mode and same issue.

We are in Microsoft Azure. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No one on Stack to guide?